# How do I set root path in Angular when using BASE tag and HTML5Mode?

Tags: angularjs

Given my basic example of an Angular app that lives in a `<base href="/test/">` directory, what is the best way to send the application back to the home (or root) path? All the links in the menu snippet (below) work, however, the "Home" link causes IE to reload the app (`HomeCtrl`, specifically) on subsequent requests.

**app.js**

```js
var basic = '<h1>{{title}}</h1><p>{{body}}</p>';

var app = angular.module('website', []);

app.config( function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', { template: basic, controller: HomeCtrl }).
        when('/about', { template: basic, controller: AboutCtrl }).
        when('/experiments', { template: basic, controller: ExperimentsCtrl }).
        when('/:alias', { template: basic, controller: PageCtrl, resolve: { alias: resolveAlias } }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode('true');
} );
```

**menu.html**

```html
<base href="/test/">
....
<div id="menu">
    <a href="./" class="btn">Home</a>
    <a href="./about" class="btn">About</a>
    <a href="./experiments" class="btn">Experiments</a>
    <a href="./unicorn" class="btn">Unicorn</a>
</div>
```

**Update**

Each request to the root, in IE9, reruns the JS file and then triggers the route events twice.

```
LOG: MainCtrl Loaded!
LOG: routeChangeStart[object Arguments]
LOG: routeChangeSuccess[object Arguments]
LOG: routeChangeStart[object Arguments]
LOG: routeChangeSuccess[object Arguments]
LOG: HomeCtrl Called!
```

Comment: just for kicks, change your otherwise directive to redirect somewhere else and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
redirectTo – {(string|function())=} – value to update $location path with and trigger route redirection.
```

So the browser redirect is part of the function you are calling.

Instead of:

```
{ redirectTo: '/' }
```

try using the same as the home route:

```
{ template: basic, controller: HomeCtrl }
```

I haven't tried this as I am not in a position to at this minute but let me know if it works.